# How to read the data ignoring the comma in columns using pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, import-from-csv

I used the follow way to read my data:

```
df=pd.read_csv("file.dat",delim_whitespace=True,header=None,skiprows=None)    
df.head()
```

and then I obtained:

```
0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0.5 

1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1.5

...
```

It is shown that all the columns (except for the last one) contain the number+','. However, I just need the number value (without the commas) for each column. How should I read the table?

Comment: Your file is comma separated, read_csv uses default separator as comma. Try removing denim_whitespace parameter and it should work

Comment: you can check 'delimiter' or 'sep' option in pandas.read_csv documentation

Comment: If that doesn't work, open the file regularly like --> with open("file.dat") as f: data = f.read(), then remove all whitespace and put it into StringIO--> data = StringIO (data.replace(" ","")), [import StringIO if python 2 , from io import StringIO if python 3] then read_csv with comma as the delimiter --> pd.read_csv(data, delimiter=",", header=None, skiprows=None)

Answer (score 0):

Your option `delim_whitespace=True` is equivalent to  `sep='\s+'` if your file has value separeted with commas ommit the line `delim_whitespace=True`, you don't need the `sep = ','` as it is the default value. 
try:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.dat", header=None, skiprows=None)
```